# Manually calling Featherlight gallery starts from first image always no matter what I click

Tags: featherlight.js

http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/893/

```
$(".column").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $.featherlightGallery($(".column"));
});
```

You can see it here.

Clicking on the second image still opens the first one if I have a click event, that triggers the manual calling of the gallery.

Am I missing something? Documentation doesn't specify much.

Comment: PRs to improve the documentation are always welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the "first item" with the `$currentTarget` option:

```
$.featherlightGallery($(".column"), {$currentTarget: $('the first item, maybe this in your case?')});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it, but it's nowhere to be found in the documentation. I'll probably do a pull request, because the documentation doesn't even have some of the basics.

Any guide on how this should be done?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, was looking for this myself. Would also appreciate a documentation update. Love featherlight

Comment: @hyp0thetical: PRs on documentation (or anything else) always welcome...