# How to set Featherlight Gallery current image when calling multiple times?

Tags: featherlight.js

The main problem I'm looking at right now is the next/previous buttons are not working as expected **after featherlightGallery() has been called more than once** -  The first click on the next button always shows the first image while the previous button always shows the 2nd to last image.

[GitHub](https://github.com/machouinard/image-gallery-preview)

The idea is to show the first 4 thumbnails from a gallery on a page.

[image: First 4 images from gallery]

When one of these thumbnails is clicked, the (hidden) gallery opens via featherlight, a click is triggered on the related image in the gallery, and the gallery behind the image is closed.  This leaves the viewer with the image they clicked and the next/previous buttons. (ignore the lack of styling!)

[image]

Every time these thumbnails are clicked, the next/previous buttons work as expected, displaying adjacent images in the gallery.

The first 4 images from the gallery shown on the page: (`#` is substituted for actual numbers.  The `data-click` attr is used in JS to trigger a click on the related gallery image)

```
<div id="intro-gallery">
    <a data-click="gi-#" class="intro" href="img/#.jpg"><div class="intro" style="background-image: url('img/#.jpg');"></div></a>
    <a data-click="gi-#" class="intro" href="img/#.jpg"><div class="intro" style="background-image: url('img/#.jpg');"></div></a>
    <a data-click="gi-#" class="intro" href="img/#.jpg"><div class="intro" style="background-image: url('img/#.jpg');"></div></a>
    <a data-click="gi-#" class="intro" href="img/#.jpg"><div class="intro" style="background-image: url('img/#.jpg');"></div></a>
</div>
```

Clicking this link opens the featherlight div without triggering any clicks or hiding the gallery (with JS).

```
<p><a class="link" href="#main-gallery-container">Gallery</a></p>
```

[image]

The first time the link is clicked, the gallery is shown and the user clicks a thumbnail, the next/previous buttons work as expected. Since the gallery is hidden after user clicks a thumbnail, they need to click the Gallery button again to see all the thumbs - **at this point, after clicking another thumbnail, the next button always shows the first image and the previous button shows the 2nd to last image**.  *Seems like the current image is set to the last image in this case*.

Inside this `#main-gallery` div are 12 `.gallery-item` divs (1 shown for brevity).

```
<div id="main-gallery" data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter=".mgi">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <a class="main" id="gi-#" href="#mgi-#">
            <div class="thumb-holder" style="background-image: url('img/{$x}.jpg');"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="mgi-wrapper">
            <div id="mgi-#" class="mgi">
                <div class="mgi-image" style="background-image: url('img/#.jpg');">
                </div>
                <div class="mgi-text">
                    <p>Some text goes here</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
"use strict";

(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    $('a.link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.featherlight.close();
  $.featherlightGallery.close();
  initGallery();
}); // Add link to view gallery, bind click.

$.featherlightGallery.prototype.afterOpen = function () {
  var link = $('<span class="single-gallery-link"><a class="link" href="#main-gallery-container">View Gallery Images</a></span>');
  $('.featherlight.single .featherlight-content').prepend(link);
  $(link).click(function () {
    $.featherlight.close();
    $.featherlightGallery.close();
    initGallery();
  });
};

$('a.intro').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  initGallery(); // get ID from data-att of initial thumbnail

  var id = $(this).data('click'); // Get same thumb in gallery and trigger a click

  var thumb = document.getElementById(id);
  $(thumb).click();
});
$('#link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  initGallery();
});

var switchToGallery = function switchToGallery(e) {
  // prevent triggered click
  e.preventDefault();
  $.featherlight.close();
  $.featherlightGallery.close();
  initGallery();
};

var initGallery = function initGallery() {
  $.featherlight('#main-gallery', {
    variant: 'onclick',
    afterOpen: function afterOpen() {
      $('a.main').featherlightGallery({
        targetAttr: 'href',
        variant: 'single',
        beforeOpen: function beforeOpen() {
          $.featherlight.close();
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
}); 
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/52611202/774793
//$.featherlightGallery($(".column"), {$currentTarget: $('the first item, maybe this in your case?')});
})(jQuery);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

EDIT: I don't like posting URLs with a limited lifespan here but for the sake of solving the problem - [temporary example](https://mark.chouinard.me/gallery/)

Comment: I appreciate your effort in describing things, but despite the lengthy explanation it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, or why it doesn't work out of the box. As always, a live example would be nice.

Comment: I completely understand!  I added a link to an online example at the bottom of the post.  After the page loads, if you click the "Gallery" link and then click an image, the next/previous links work as expected.  Once that single image modal is closed, click the "Gallery" link again - this time the next/previous links go to the first and 2nd-to-last images, respectively.   I'm looking into the navigateTo method you mentioned.  Thanks.

Comment: Also - the trouble is only with the gallery, not the first 4 images.  Any time those are clicked the next/previous links work as expected.  Also #2 - It's the develop branch on GH in case that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The library is confused, `$.featherlightGallery.current().$currentTarget[0]` seems to be a detached copy and not part of `$.featherlightGallery.current().slides()` so navigation is lost.

I'm not too sure what is going on and don't have the time to delve into it further.
I would try with `persist: true`. Also looks like you are constantly re-initing the gallery, you should bind it once.

Comment: Ended up creating a "shadow" gallery and using it like the initial four images -  this "shadow" gallery displays all thumbnails in a featherlight modal and when a thumbnail is clicked, that modal is hidden and a click on the matching image in the gallery is triggered.  No doubt this is incorrect but it works as expected.